# How convert multidimensional array to two dimensional array

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

Here, my code feats value form text file; and create matrices as multidimensional array, but the problem is the code create more then two dimensional array, that I can't manipulate, I need two dimensional array, how I do that?

Explain algorithm of my code:

**Moto of code:**
My code fetch value from a specific folder, each folder contain 7 'txt' file, that generate from one user, in this way multiple folder contain multiple data of multiple user.

step1: Start a 1st for loop, and control it using how many folder have in specific folder,and in variable 'path' store the first path of first folder.

step2: Open the path and fetch data of 7 txt file using 2nd for loop.after feats, it close 2nd for loop and execute the rest code.

step3: Concat the data of 7 txt file in one 1d array.

step4(Here the problem arise): Store the 1d arry of each folder as 2d array.end first for loop.

Code:

```
import numpy as np
from array import *
import os
f_path='Result'
array_control_var=0

#for feacth directory path
for (path,dirs,file) in os.walk(f_path):
    if(path==f_path):
        continue
    f_path_1= path +'\page_1.txt'
    #Get data from page1 indivisualy beacuse there string type data exiest
    pgno_1 = np.array(np.loadtxt(f_path_1, dtype='U', delimiter=','))

    #only for page_2.txt
    f_path_2= path +'\page_2.txt'
    with open(f_path_2) as f:
        str_arr = ','.join([l.strip() for l in f])
    pgno_2 = np.asarray(str_arr.split(','), dtype=int)

    #using loop feach data from those text file.datda type = int
    for j in range(3,8):

    #store file path using variable
        txt_file_path=path+'\page_'+str(j)+'.txt'


        if os.path.exists(txt_file_path)==True:

            #genarate a variable name that auto incriment with for loop
            foo='pgno_'+str(j)
        else:
            break

        #pass the variable name as string and store value
        exec(foo + " = np.array(np.loadtxt(txt_file_path, dtype='i', delimiter=','))")

    #z=np.array([pgno_2,pgno_3,pgno_4,pgno_5,pgno_6,pgno_7])




    #marge all array from page 2 to rest in single array in one dimensation
    f_array=np.concatenate((pgno_2,pgno_3,pgno_4,pgno_5,pgno_6,pgno_7), axis=0)

    #for first time of the loop assing this value
    if array_control_var==0:
        main_f_array=f_array
    else:
        #here the problem arise 
        main_f_array=np.array([main_f_array,f_array])
    array_control_var+=1
print(main_f_array)
```

current my code generate array like this(for 3 folder)

> ```
> [
>  array([[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]),
>  array([0,0,0])
> ]
> ```

Note: I don't know how many dimension it have

But I want

> ```
> [
> array( 
>   [0,0,0]
>   [0,0,0]
>   [0,0,0])
> ]
> ```

Comment: the top list has 11 zeros, but the bottom one just 9, so you can't reshape unless you delete something. is that correct?

Comment: No, it's no matter how many zero contain the array, First array in more thane two dimensional array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to write a recursive code that recursively flattens the list of lists into one list. It gives the desired output for your case, but I did not try it for many other inputs(And it is buggy for certain cases such as :`list =[0,[[0,0,0],[0,0,0]],[0,0,0]]`)...

```
flat = []

def main():
    list =[[[0,0,0],[0,0,0]],[0,0,0]]
    recFlat(list)
    print(flat)

def recFlat(Lists):
    if len(Lists) == 0:
        return Lists
    head, tail = Lists[0], Lists[1:]
    if isinstance(head, (list,)):
        recFlat(head)
        return  recFlat(tail)
    else:
        return flat.append(Lists)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

My idea behind the code was to traverse the head of each list, and check whether it is an instance of a list or an element. If the head is an element, this means I have a flat list and I can return the list. Else, I should recursively traverse more.