# Data type conversion for numpy array, object to int32 in Python

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, numpy-ndarray

how I convert dtype=object to int 32, I need to do this for insert array in right row of 2 d array, you can see in output. np.insert() not work properly becuse of the miss match of type, so I need to convert.

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.zeros(2,object)
arr[0] = np.array([0,0,0])
arr[1] = np.array([0,0,0])
p=np.insert(arr, 2, np.array([1,1,1]), 0)
print(p)
print(arr.dtype)
```

Output:

> [array([0, 0, 0]) array([0, 0, 0]) 1 1 1]
>
> > object

Comment: What is your expected output? Are you trying to [flatten](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html) numpy array?

Comment: i need [[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[1,1,1]] this out put

Comment: you can see this post, for better understanding of my problem
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54715610/numpy-insert-function-insert-array-into-wrong-index/54716917?noredirect=1#comment96220212_54716917

Comment: I don't think using dtype object for that is a good idea.

Comment: so what is best solusation.

Comment: i stuck from 24 hours, still i not get a proper solusation, you can see my another post there I code in some different way
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54711937/how-convert-multidimensional-array-to-two-dimensional-array/54712965#54712965

Comment: Two links are difarent

Comment: Is it possible to convert dtype=object to dtype=int32 for nmpy array?

Comment: Make ' arr'  a list. You can convert an object array to an in32 array as long as the objects in the array are compatible with int32 which in your case are not.

Comment: Or make `arr` a 2D `int32` array from the start.

Comment: Figure out  why your array is object dtype in first place,.  Why are you still trying to use insert?

Comment: Finally i got my salutation, Thank you all especially @hpaulj.